# Spark: does DataFrameWriter have to be a blocking step?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing, partitioning

I have data partitioned by a column (say, `id`) and I have this dataset saved some place. Every now and then, I get a smaller incremental dataset with the same structure and I essentially have to upsert my existing data based on my `id` with a `date` column deciding which record is the newest. (I don't write it in the same place, I save the whole new blob some place else.)

There are two ways I've been doing this - either grouping in a window and taking the row with the highest `date`. Or via `dropDuplicates`, relying on the fact, that my data is ordered. (I'd rather use the former, but I've been trying various things.)

The one big issue is that each `id` group is not negligible (a few gigabytes), so I was hoping Spark (with `n` workers) would understand that since I'm reading `id`-partitioned data and writing `id`-partitioned data, it would process `n` ids at once and continually write them to my storage, taking new ids as it's finished with the previous ones.

Unfortunately, what seems to be happening, is that Spark processes all my `id` groups in one big job (and spills to disk, naturally) before writing anything to disk. It gets really really slow.

**The question is thus:** Is there a way to force Spark to process these groups and write them as soon as they're ready? Again, they are partitioned, so no other task will affect my partition.

---

Here's a bit of code that reproduces the problem:

```
# generate dummy data first
import random
from typing import List
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, col, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

def gen_data(n: int) -> List[tuple]:
    names = 'foo, bar, baz, bak'.split(', ')
    return [(random.randint(1, 25), random.choice(names), datetime.today() - timedelta(days=random.randint(1, 100))) \
          for j in range(n)]

def get_df(n: int) -> DataFrame:
    return spark.createDataFrame(gen_data(n), ['id', 'name', 'date'])

n = 10_000
df = get_df(n)
dd = get_df(n*10)

df.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('id').parquet('outputs/first')
dd.write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('id').parquet('outputs/second')
```

`d1` and `d2` are both partitioned by `id` and so is the resulting dataset, but it's not reflected in the plan:

```
w = Window().partitionBy('id').orderBy(desc('date'))

d1 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/first')
d2 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/second')

d1.union(d2).\
  withColumn('rn', row_number().over(w)).filter(col('rn') == 1).drop('rn').\
  write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('id').parquet('outputs/window')
```

I also tried to explicitly state the partition key (otherwise the code is the same):

```
d1 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/first').repartition('id')
d2 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/second').repartition('id')

d1.union(d2).\
  withColumn('rn', row_number().over(w)).filter(col('rn') == 1).drop('rn').\
  write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('id').parquet('outputs/window2')
```

Here's the same using `dropDuplicates`:

```
d1 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/first')
d2 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/second')

d1.union(d2).\
  dropDuplicates(subset=['id']).\
  write.mode('overwrite').partitionBy('id').parquet('outputs/window3')
```

I also tried emphasising that my union is still partitioned using something like this, but again to no avail:

```
df.union(d2).repartition('id').\
  .withColumn...
```

---

I could list all partitions (`id`s), load them one by one while leveraging partition pruning, deduplicating and writing. But that seems like extra boilerplate that shouldn't be necessary. Or is it possible to do this via `foreach`?

---

**Update (2018-03-27):**

Turns out, the information about partitioning is indeed present in the window functionality in one way or another, because when I filter at the very end, partition pruning on the inputs does take place:

```
d1 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/first')
d2 = spark.read.parquet('outputs/second')

w = Window().partitionBy('id', 'name').orderBy(desc('date'))

d1.union(d2).withColumn('rn', row_number().over(w)).filter(col('rn') == 1).filter(col('id') == 12).explain(True)
```

Results in

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(4) Filter (isnotnull(rn#387) && (rn#387 = 1))
+- Window [row_number() windowspecdefinition(id#187, name#185, date#186 DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS rn#387], [id#187, name#185], [date#186 DESC NULLS LAST]
   +- *(3) Sort [id#187 ASC NULLS FIRST, name#185 ASC NULLS FIRST, date#186 DESC NULLS LAST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#187, name#185, 200)
         +- Union
            :- *(1) FileScan parquet [name#185,date#186,id#187] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/.../spark_perf_partitions/outputs..., PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(id#187), (id#187 = 12)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<name:string,date:timestamp>
            +- *(2) FileScan parquet [name#191,date#192,id#193] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:/.../spark_perf_partitions/outputs..., PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(id#193), (id#193 = 12)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<name:string,date:timestamp>
```

So it indeed only reads two partitions, one per each file. So I could, instead of looping, just run the code with one filter at a time (the filter being between the window function and `.write`). Tedious and not very practical, but potentially faster than spilling everything to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is exactly how spark partitioning works. So it computes the whole lineage and then write in a partitioned form on the disk. There are several advantages for that. One of the important reason is parallel write. So when the computation is done spark can write all the partitions in parallel on the disk. This significantly improves the performance.

If you want to write as an when the data is ready you might as well filter on the dataframe by different Ids and compute the process in a loop and write. However, in my experience this approach requires several iterations on the same dataframe resulting huge performance loss.

Comment: What use is a parallel writer when all my data (100s of GBs) is on disk (which had to be written there in the first place)? The whole point of my question is to keep the data in memory to speed up writes and avoid spilling to disk.

Comment: If you want to write serially then spark needs to evaluate the dan. Several times. It will filter the input dataset based on the partition ID and then do the operation, finally save. This process is more time consuming. If you don't want to spill data to disk you might want to increase the shuffle memory fraction

Comment: The issue is that the data is way bigger than my memory, so this is not really an option. But thanks anyway!